# How to send link to default sms app with Intent?

Tags: android, sms

I want to open my default SMS application with intent from my application and to send LINK to some webpage , but when I try code bellow , sms app want recognize link . My current code is

```
            Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290737/android-message-intent");
            startActivity(smsIntent);
```

I want something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as below:

```
    Uri smsToUri = Uri.parse( "smsto:" );
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, smsToUri);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290737/android-message-intent");
    startActivity(smsIntent);
```